# How to bind DataGrid to more collections?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a DataGrid bounded to a ObservableCollection (`StoredSequences<Sequence>`):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding StoredSequences}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NameEnglish}" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The Sequence model:

```
public class Sequence : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Sequence() { }

    private int _id;
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }
    private string _nameEnglish;
    public string NameEnglish
    {
        get
        {
            return _nameEnglish;
        }
        set
        {
            _nameEnglish = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NameEnglish");
        }
    }
    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
    private string _category;
    public string Category
    {
        get
        {
            return _category;
        }
        set
        {
            _category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Category");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I want to add two ComboBoxes in the last two columns of the grid, with ItemsSource bounded to other ObservableCollections (`Values<int>` and `Categories<string>` generated in ViewModel). I could add TextBoxes, because the `Sequence` contains `Value` and `Category`, but I want the user to be able to select the items. I've tried this:

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The problem is that the ComboBoxes are empty. This is one of the errors received:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Values' property not found on 'object' ''Sequence' (HashCode=31195541)'. BindingExpression:Path=Values; DataItem='Sequence' (HashCode=31195541); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=ComboBox1'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')`

**What is the correct way to bind the DataGrid to more collections? Or how can I display ComboBoxes on CellEdit and TextBox otherwise?**

Comment: the `StoredSequences` `ObservableCollection` stores `StoredSequences`-es or `Sequence`? I do not fully understand. Btw I would do it like `StoredSequences` are an `ObservableCollection` of view models

Comment: @ntohl It stores Sequence.

Comment: Can You paste the Sequence class please? I'm interested in the Values and Categories properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from your error message that the binding is failing because the framework can't find the Values and Categories properties on objects of type Sequence. This is happening because each row in your DataGrid has the underlying Sequence as its DataContext.

If you don't want to add the Values and Categories collection to the Sequence object, then what you need to do is change your Bindings so that they bind to the parent DataContext, not the row DataContext.

Try this example, which redirects the binding to the DataGrid's DataContext:

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Categories}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've spotted that. Glad it helped you enough.